# Intel Wireless card not detected by Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, wireless-networking, drivers

I have an Intel AC-3168 wireless card. So it worked fine in Windows until I installed Ubuntu 20.10 as dual-boot. After restarting back into Windows, the wireless card was not detected. In device manager, it says code 10: failed to start. Operation not permitted.
Also in the troubleshooting wizard, it says the card is having driver- or hardware-related issues.
However, the wireless works fine in Ubuntu. Can someone help me to fix the problem? I need my network back.

`lshw -c net` output:

```
description: Wireless interface
       product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:22:00.0
       logical name: wlp34s0
       version: 10
       serial: 98:8d:46:5b:17:79
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-30-generic firmware=29.163394017.0 3168-29.ucode ip=192.168.1.227 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:73 memory:f7500000-f7501fff
```

[Not detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcCXM.png)
[Device Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeWEv.png)
[Troubleshooting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0GuS.png)

Comment: Go to:  https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/94854/Intel-Dual-Band-Wireless-AC-3168  and see if ProSet can help you reset the network card.

Comment: Is it the zip file

Comment: Look for this in the link   Intel® PROSet/Wireless Software and Drivers for IT Admins

Comment: Also I have specific drivers for my MSI motherboard

Comment: Ok so it is the zip file

Comment: Which inf do I use

Comment: On the first link I provided, look at the Second Item (ProSet) and try using ProSet in Windows 10 to see if it can fix the card settings and driver.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116591/discussion-between-nineplustenequalstwentyone-and-john).

Comment: Discussions are useless to me. I get no value or credit from them so maybe someone there can help you

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: have you ever tried to reinstall it and update it in the device manager?

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: I wonder if the Linux dual boot has changed hardware parameters in the card. I have not seen that, but it could be a possibility.  If the download from Intel did not work, try updating via Device Manager..  Open Device Manager, scroll down to the Network section and open the Intel 3268 network card. Go to the Driver tab  .  You can Update the driver, Roll back the driver, and Uninstall the driver. Do not initially uninstall (because the Intel package does not work, you said). Try Update or Roll back.

Comment: Roll back is greyed out and update says the latest drivers are already installed

Comment: I am not sure at this point what the dual-boot did to break the driver nor how to fix it now. Everything has been tried. You may need to try a different USB Wireless card.

Comment: Maybe I should change some GRUB options